# Python Gets JSON Response As Single Value Dict

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Using python to send json requests to a rest api. The initial request is to login! The login, when successful, returns a key to be used with every subsequent request. Login server is down at this very moment, so I've modified my code just as an example to show the issue I face.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import json

r = requests.get('myApi')
data = json.loads(r.content)
print(r.status_code)

for key, value in data.items():
    print key
    print value

apikey = data['startRow']
```

The output is;

```
401
response
{u'status': 401, u'startRow': 0, u'totalRows': 1, u'data': {u'errors': [u'Credentials are not valid']}, u'endRow': 1}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zzzz\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    apikey = data['startRow']
KeyError: 'startRow'
```

How can a specific param in the dict be referenced? It *appears* as though the value is actually the whole response itself is the value, and not startRow or errors, etc.

Comment: Btw `requests.Response` objects have a nice `.json()` method, which will deal with decoding the content without an explicit `json.loads`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line;

```
apikey = data['response']['startRow']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the convenient `requests.Response.json()` to let `requests` take care of parsing the JSON response:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('myApi')
data = r.json()
apikey = data['startRow']
```